# What does it mean start a worker process (w3wp.exe) in debug mode?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, w3wp

All,  According the [WAS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735084(v=ws.10).aspx).The document says the worker process is managed by WAS .

But I found when typing `w3wp /?`  There is a debug flag.

```
-debug 
   This option launches a worker process using the default 
   application host config file.  By default, it will use 
   site id 1.
```

What does mean start worker process in debug mode? In what case we want to start a work process with debug option ? thanks.

**Added**

I didn't known why I got a exception when run `w3wp.exe -debug`.

> ERROR: There has been an error during processing of this command. 
>   Please check the event log and see if any errors or warnings have been
>   logged.

When I checked the log. It looks like:

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service failed to set the application
>   pool for the application '/xxxx' in site '1'. The data field contains
>   the error number.

[image]

Comment: My guess is it's only for the code of w3wp.exe itself (not what it is hosting) to be debugged yes/no.

Comment: @MarvinSmit thanks your reply. You mean for debugging the w3wp.exe native code ?

Comment: Yeah. Microsofties using WinDbg on a process which is W3WP.exe. Maybe it can do mem-dumps when debug is on. Or it's just another extra "try/catch" when debug is off?

Comment: Actually I was reading the tutorial of Open Cover. in the `run against with IIS `part. it should add debug option. I just didn't understand what it used for . So I post a question here . I google with the keywords `w3wp.exe debug option` . Didn't get what I hope for so far.

Comment: And I knew WinDbg can debug with the native code(c++). But If `WinDbg` need to debug w3wp . Is it necessary to start with `-debug`?

Comment: w3wp.exe is a c++ written program AFAIK. It creates the default appdomain and loads the clr. Debugging is possible without -debug, but the -debug flag might write additional info to eventlog/OutputDebugString() during normal process runtime. No debguger attached.. Log Trace debuggging?

Comment: @MarvinSmit I think the link provider by Shaun would be the answer of your question. It's really the fact that it help to the w3wp process be attach by a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183480 it switches the security context of the running user which is not its normal mode of operation - I suppose this would make it easier to then attach a debugger and other utilities.

Comment: ++1 Thanks your kindly review my question.It is really appreciated that author can help to review the question in SO . I just wonder why `OpenCover` need start w3wp in debug mode. I had thought all the debug and code information can be found in the PDB file of .net assemebly. Is it right ? Thanks.

Comment: OpenCover is a tool for use against testing utilities such as nunit and mstest but it can be used against other processes (though I personally disagree using it this way I understand that some people have n other recourse). For OpenCover and the target process to communicate using events and shared memory blocks they need to have the same permissions (and that can be very tricky to get right) - by running w3wp in debug it is not running in the same context as the user and this the permissions is less of an issue. It also stops people tryign to do this in production system - a big no-no IMO.